# sort table by three columns

Tags: mysql, sorting, multiple-columns

Looking for a way to sort orders by three conditions.   I can get two of them with out a problem.   Example table:

```
Buyer  Qty  Item_ID
James  1    12345
Jack   1    34564
John   3    13445
Kevin  1    83243
Bill   2    23434
Jack   3    23423
```

so the trick here is to group buyers first,
then qty
then item_id

Jack has two orders that need to be grouped then pulled and shipped together
The rest of the orders need to be grouped by qty then sorted by item_ID

The output would be like:

```
Buyer  Qty  Item_ID
Jack   1    34564
Jack   3    23423
James  1    12345
Kevin  1    83243
Bill   2    23434
Bob    2    23444
John   3    13445
```

Buyers don't need to be sorted just grouped for multiple orders
sort by qty, item_id separated Jacks orders.   we get 100's of orders a day, multiple from same buyer.   Orders with same number of items need to be sorted by item_id to simplify pulling stock from one end of the room to the other.   It seems that grouping the buyers would work but haven't figured it out yet.

the most reasonable query so far:

```
    select * FROM orders
    WHERE printed = 0 
    AND status = 'completed' 
    AND address_name <> '' 
    group by buyer
    ORDER BY qty, id;
```

this query skips the multiple orders from the same buyer and gives the rest sorted properly.

I've implemented Answer 1 with success thank you!

Comment: Do you have a query where you've attempted to do this?

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking you just need an `order by Buyer, qty, item_ID`  not a "group by"?  Seeing expected output would be useful as well

Comment: I hope you got the answer for your first question. So, you would have accepted the answer for it. If you have another question, it would be better to create a new one without elaborating the existing solved one. It's not only you benefit from this question and answer. So keep to that format then the others could utilize the thread. Btw, the error is self explanatory. You don't have a item_number column in your paypal_ipn_orders table.(Confirm that, it might be item_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will give you the exact result required. In inner query it generates the count of the same buyer instances. Then it joins with the original table from buyer column. Then get it sorted by the count of same buyer instances descending and by other columns ascending.

```
SELECT table1.buyer, qty, item_id 
FROM orders table1,
  (SELECT buyer, COUNT(*) as count FROM orders GROUP BY buyer) as table2
  WHERE table1.buyer = table2.buyer 
  ORDER BY count DESC, qty, item_id;
```

Refer this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cccc/29).